# How to plot facet histogram with customized underflow/overflow bins in Python3?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, matplotlib, seaborn

I have a pandas dataframe with several columns (region, date, profit). I would like a histogram of the profit faceted by region and by date. But the profit column data has a long tail on each side, meaning there are 5 counts of profit less than $10, and 280483 counts of profit between $400-$450, and then 6 counts of profit larger than $100000.

What I would like to do is to create a histogram with customized bins so that it shows multiple bins for $400-$450 and just 1 bin for below $400, and 1 bin for above $450, and hopefully the columns in the histogram are above the same width.

What I have now:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
fixed_bin = list(np.arange(400,450,5))
fixed_bin.insert(0,0)
fixed_bin.append(150000)
fig = sns.FacetGrid(df, col = 'region', row = 'date',
                    margin_titles = True, aspect = 1.4)
fig.map(sns.distplot, 'profit', kde = False, bins = fixed_bin, color = 'r')
```

However, this gives me an evenly distributed X-axis that goes from 0 to 150000. All my data (between 400-450) are still squeezed in the middle and hard to see the real histogram for that middle section. How can I make the tails on both ends (underflow and overflow bins) into two small bins that are same width as the bins in the middle?

Thank you very much for your help!!

Comment: Do you mean non-equally spaced bins?

Comment: Yes, essentially I want my bins to be (0,400],(400,410],(410,420],(420,430],(430,440],(440,450],(450,150000). But when they show up as histogram bars, I want each bar represent the count in each bins to be equal width. Therefore the X-axis would be scaled to my bins, not normal 0 to 150000 scale.

Comment: Look at the histgram functions of numpy and scipy, I think they support these bins. As you already did, you could manually adjust the tails.

Comment: My problem is not with the binning, as you can see, I already did the bin with numpy. The problem is for the bins to show up on the X-axis correctly at the same width (let's say size 2), not the mathematical-width (150000).

Comment: Please edit your code, `df` is missing,

Comment: Also the line `fig.map(sns.distplot, 'profit', kde = False,` is probably missing the `df` before `profit`.

Answer (score 2):

My first thought was to do the binning and the plotting separately.
But I could not find that `matplotlib.pyplot.bar` or `seaborn.barplot` offer
custom bin sizes.

So we have to trick `seaborn.distplot` or `matplotlib.pyplot.hist` 
(the function behind it).

```
import numpy as np

import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# add another bin to dump all overflow values
# same size as the others
fixed_bin = list(np.arange(400, 455, 5))

# add another bin to dump all underflow values
# same size as the others
fixed_bin.insert(0, 395)

print(fixed_bin)

some_upper_boundary = 500

data = np.random.randint(300, high=some_upper_boundary, size=1000)

# use boolean indexing do move the data from 450 to 150000 into the
# last bin

in_first_bin = np.logical_and(data >= 0, data < 400)
in_last_bin = np.logical_and(data > 450, data <= some_upper_boundary)

data[in_first_bin] = 397
data[in_last_bin] = 447

#print(data)
ax = sns.distplot(data, bins=fixed_bin)


# Set the tick positions
ax.set_xticks(fixed_bin)

my_custom_ticklabels = list(map(str, fixed_bin))
print(my_custom_ticklabels)

my_custom_ticklabels[0] = 'under\nflow'
my_custom_ticklabels[-1] = 'over\nflow'

# Set the tick labels
ax.set_xticklabels(my_custom_ticklabels)

plt.show()
```

I will add some formatting later:

- add a custom tick label to the plot. The last bin could be 'after'.
- do the same trick for the first bin and adjust the label to 'before'.

[image]

Comment: I would say that the resulting histogram looks bad and misleading. And the pdf around the spurious peaks looks extremely wrong. I think there should be better ways of visualising that.